# Google Colaboratory上のNVIDIAドライバーのバージョン変更の方法が知りたいです

Tags: google-colaboratory, cuda

2021年7月にGoogle Colaboratory上でPythonとTensorflowを使ったノートブックを作成し，GPUで正しく実行できることを確認しましたが，同じノートブックを2022年1月の現時点で実行すると計算結果が異なったものとなります．

原因のひとつはNVIDIAドライバのバージョンアップと考えています．

`nvidia-smi` でドライバのバージョンを確認すると，2022年1月の現時点では
以下の通り `460.32.03` と確認できますが，これを `445` に変更したいです．

```
Wed Jan 19 01:44:31 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 495.46       Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

CUDAのバージョン変更方法はわかるのですが，NVIDIAドライバのバージョン変更の方法がわかりません．どなたかご存じでしたら教えていただけないでしょうか．よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 英語版の質問 [How can I change NVIDIA driver version on Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70765617/9014308) へのコメントで「出来ない」ということで解決したようですね。

Comment: @kunif さん，おっしゃるように英語版でreputationが68000を超える方から「You can't.」と回答がありました．コメントありがとうございます．

Comment: 情報共有のために自己回答でもしておいてください。